# Adding current date to DATE table mysql ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am having some problems getting my date into my SQL table. **I do not use datetime, but date.**

This is the code I use, and the problem is that my SQL server doesn't recognize $date_add as a date and just puts the default 0000-00-00 in the date section...

```
if (isset($_POST['postbutton'])){
                $articlepost = nl2br($_POST['article'])."<br>";

                date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
                $datepic = date(YYYY-MM-DD);


                $pictureurls = $_SESSION['urlpost'];
                $thumbnail = 123;
                $title = $_POST['title'];
                $date_add = $datepic;
                $articlepostimg = $articlepost.$pictureurls;

                $insertpost = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title,post,date_add,thumbnail) VALUES (:title,:post,:date_add,:thumbnail)");
                $insertpost->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':post' => $articlepostimg, ':date_add' => $date_add, ':thumbnail' => $thumbnail));
                unset($_SESSION['urlpost']);

            }
```

Here is what I see in my database after I submit my form:

[image]

Comment: You could use the built-in SQL [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function using `DATETIME` as your column's setting, or a few other similar column types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`$datepic  = date("Y-m-d");`

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) are the docs for `date()`

As for the question added in your comments, after you retrieve your date you'll need to do something like the following, where `$orig_date` is assigned the date retrieved from the database. As for converting it to Norwegian, I think you'd have to look into `setlocale()`, which I think warrants a different question.

`$formatted_date = date('j, M Y', strtotime($orig_date));`

Comment: You dont know how I can get the norwegian translation out when I fetch the date back?

Comment: @FriedBitz fo' sho. Not sure what you mean, what does is a Norwegian date look like? Post an example of how you'd like it to look upon fetching it.

Comment: I'd like to have: 6. Mars 2014 instead of 6. March 2014. So change the month name :)

Comment: However, does that change the month name aswell? From English -> Norwegian?

Comment: @FriedBitz I don't know about converting to Norwegian, perhaps post another question?

Comment: @FriedBitz See [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22212600/) it's what I use (taken from my own code library). You're welcome to use it. Call it my "contribution" ;-) and no need to accept my answer, keep the one you accepted, but an upvote would be nice if it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either double quote or quotes to make `date()` function work propely

```
$datepic = date('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just to add to already given answers after seeing OP asked for a language conversion in Norwegian, and by no means is it meant to step on anyone's feet, but as a complimentary answer.

You can use the following month conversion code which are in French, but you can easily modify it in Norwegian.

Notice that "Mars" is spelled the same way.

(This taken from my own code library)

```
<?php
// enter date format 2011-01-31 (Y-m-d)
function date_in_french ($date){
$week_name = array("Dimanche","Lundi","Mardi","Mercredi","Jeudi","Vendredi","Samedi");
$month_name=array("","Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin","Juillet","Août",
"Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Décembre");

$split = preg_split('/-/', $date);
$year = $split[0];
$month = round($split[1]);
$day = round($split[2]);

$week_day = date("w", mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
return $date_fr = $week_name[$week_day] .' '. $day .' '. $month_name[$month] .' '. $year;
}
$currentDate=date('Y-m-d');
echo "Current Date: ";
echo date('D')." ".date('d')." ".date('M')." ".date('Y');
echo "<br>";
echo "Date in French => ".date_in_french($currentDate);
?>
```